# Variables globales con Jest - React

Tags: reactjs, jest

Tengo un componente que utiliza un componente global:

```
export class ContenedorAsistente extends AsistenteBase<propTypes, estados> {
    referenciaAsistente: any;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
}
.
.
.
}
```

Este obtiene el valor por referencia de un `<div>`:

```
<div className="wizard-container col-md-12" ref={(ref) => this.referenciaAsistente = ref} style={{ marginBottom: "40px" }}>
.
.
.
<div>
```

He intentado con mock, creando un componente inicializado, un objeto con valores iniciales, pero igual en la prueba me muestra que el valor

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

Pero en modo desarrollo y producción, el componente si trabaja bien y efectivamente.
Si me pueden ayudar con alguna pista o implementación para lograr emular el la variable global
Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una manera de poder manejar una variable global en react, que referencia a un objeto de otro componente.
Cree una función que se encargue de recibir el objeto referenciado.

```
foo: any;
  obtenerRef(ref){
    this.foo= ref;
  }

render()
{
  return (<Boo ref={this.obtenerRef.bind(this)} />    )
}
```

De esta manera el objeto global usando librería de jest en la prueba puedo obtenerla así `const instancia = wrapper.instance() as Boo` el objeto global `this.foo` consultandolo instancia.foo  y lograr la cobertura llamando por separado a la función que que cree nueva